# Find values from the Nested Dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Something I'm doing incorrect, but I got data with list of nested dict, I need to pull the value and store in the output dict.
Data:

```
[{
  "encoding":"json",
  "result": {
     "aclList":[
        {
           "chipName":"",
           "countersEnabled":true,
           "countersIncomplete":false,
           "dynamic":false,
           "name":"FW-RULE-IN",
           "readonly":false,
           "sequence":[
              {
                 "convertSymbols":true,
                 "sequenceNumber":1,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 1"
              },
              {
                 "convertSymbols":true,
                 "sequenceNumber":2,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 2"
              },
              {
                 "convertSymbols":true,
                 "sequenceNumber":3,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 3"
              },]}]}}]
```

Like to put `sequenceNumber`, `text` values in to output result in Dict.

here is the code I got, but not working, how to fix it?

```
def parse_data(data):
    rules = {}
    acllist = []

    for k, v in data[0].items():
        for h, j in k['result'].items():
            for i in h['aclList'][0]:
                    for l in i[0]['sequence']:
                            rules['NUM'] = int(j['sequenceNumber'])
                            rules['TEXT_RULES'] = j['text']
                            acllist.append(rules.copy())
                            print (j['sequenceNumber'], j['text'])
return acllist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there can be multiple elements to these lists. If there aren't you could simplify to.

```
for dct in data[0]['result']['aclList'][0]['sequence']:
    rules['NUM'] = int(dct['sequenceNumber'])
    rules['TEXT_RULES'] = dct['text']
    acllist.append(rules.copy())
    print (inner['sequenceNumber'], dct['text'])
```

However if you want to iterate through every list and gather the elements for each version, it would look more like this:

```
def parse_data(data):
    acllist = []
    
    # for each dict in the initial list
    for dct in data:
        # for each list in the ['aclList'] key of the ['result'] key
        for lst in dct['result']['aclList']:
            # for each inner dict in the ['sequence'] key
            for inner in lst['sequence']:
                rules = {}
                rules['NUM'] = int(inner['sequenceNumber'])
                rules['TEXT_RULES'] = inner['text']
                acllist.append(rules.copy())
                print (inner['sequenceNumber'], inner['text'])
    return acllist

data =[{
  "encoding":"json",
  "result": {
     "aclList":[
        {
           "chipName":"",
           "countersEnabled":True,
           "countersIncomplete":False,
           "dynamic":False,
           "name":"FW-RULE-IN",
           "readonly":False,
           "sequence":[
              {
                 "convertSymbols":True,
                 "sequenceNumber":1,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 1"
              },
              {
                 "convertSymbols":True,
                 "sequenceNumber":2,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 2"
              },
              {
                 "convertSymbols":True,
                 "sequenceNumber":3,
                 "text":"TEST: RULE 3"
              },]}]}}]
print(parse_data(data))
```

Where you went wrong is that you are iterating through the key/values of you `dict`s.

```
for k, v in data[0].items():
```

`k` here would contain `"encoding"` and `"result"`.
And then you are trying to iterate through those keys.

```
for h, j in k['result'].items():
```

But what you are essentially doing here is saying:

```
k = "result"
for h, j in k['result'].items():
```

Or:

```
for h, j in "result"['result'].items():
```

You can see why this would throw an error.